# AlertService directive in JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I am using JHipster 3.3.0 and generated code using JDL.

Out of the box, each entity has its own popup dialog page for editing and saving data, i.e. `{entity}-dialog.html`. And after clicking the Save button, the dialog will close then the entity list page (i.e. `{entity}s.html`) will display the alert message '`A new <entity name> is created/updated with identifier {primary key}`' to indicate outcome of save by using **`<jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>`**.

Now I am implementing a one-to-many relationship for 2 entities, say User and Account(i.e. a User can have many Accounts)
 such that the editing and saving of both entities happen in the same User page(i.e. User-dialog.html).

All Accounts of the User are displayed in an Account table, each row of the table will have a Save button to save data 
of the Account after editing the data in the row.

This is all working fine. However, I noticed after clicking the Save button of Account row, I can see the background User list page
displaying the alert message mentioned above rather then in the current page.

I can't figure out how to display the alert message in the current page as opposed in the entity list page, which is the 
default behavior.

**I am missing some logic here. Any idea?**

Basically, the `<jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>` in my `<entity>-dialog.html` page is ignored and won't display message for outcome of successful save except for error message from Form validation.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Answer (score 2):

Ooops,silly me. Just found the answer.

The alert message 'A new  is created/updated with identifier {primary key}' was displayed because the tag `<jhi-alert></jhi-alert>` was used, it was never 
`<jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>`.

Comment: <jhi-alert></jhi-alert> actually catches all Alerts, even the <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error> alerts.